# Hugo - How to display an image in related content

Tags: hugo

I'm trying to display up to three related articles at the bottom of a blog post using Hugo.

I have some test code where I get data for front matter fields like Title and Summary, but I can't access Image.

Not sure what I am doing wrong

```
{{ $related := .Site.RegularPages.Related . | first 3 }}
{{ with $related }}
<div class="related-content">
  <h2>Related content</h2>
  <ul class="article-gallery">
    {{ range . }}
    <li>
      <div class="card">
        <a class="button" href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">
          <img src="" alt  ="">
        </a>
        <div>
          <h3>{{ .Title }}</h3>
        </div>
        <pre>
          {{.RelPermalink}}
          {{.Title}}
          {{.Summary}}
          {{.}}
          {{.ReadingTime}}
        </pre>

        <!-- Cannot Access Image -->
        <pre>
          {{.Image}}
        </pre>
      </div>
    </li>

    {{ end }}
  </ul>
</div>
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom, user-defined data elements in a page's front matter needs to be accessed through `.Params`:

```
{{ .Params.Image }}
```

See [The Hugo Docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter/#user-defined)

**Note:** there is a predfined "image**s**" (with an 's') that can be accessed directly. Did you mean to use that instead?